# Make appear HUGE numbers

Tags: c, math, numbers, ieee-754

I've created a simple arithmetic program involving logs and exp, but I cant get really huge number (bigger 10^300).

Using `long double`, my program says infinity, but I've been asked to try to get a closer approximation than "infinity". I think that IEEE 754 would be fine, but I don't know which format I'm using right now or how to switch to IEEE 754.

Comment: If you post an example of the code, it would be easier to present good ideas that would work for you.

Comment: If you don't know which format you're using, it's almost certainly IEEE 754 binary64 (a.k.a., "double precision").  The largest representable finite value in that format is 2^1024 - 2^971, or approximately `1.79 * 10^308`.  So it wouldn't be surprising if you're encountering overflows beyond that value.

Answer (score 2):

You may use some arbitrary precision library such as https://gmplib.org/

You also may try to find out if your compiler supports some non standard larger double type like gcc's `__float128`. But these solutions are obviously not portable.